# How to center squares under each other using OpenGL?

Tags: c, opengl

I want to have my 2 squares underneath and also centered in the window.

I have the following code:

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    glVertex2f(-0.8f, 0.1f);
    glVertex2f(-0.2f, 0.1f);
    glVertex2f(-0.2f, 0.7f);
    glVertex2f(-0.8f, 0.7f);

    glColor3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    glVertex2f(-0.7f, -0.6f);
    glVertex2f(-0.1f, -0.6f);
    glVertex2f(-0.1f,  0.0f);
    glVertex2f(-0.7f,  0.0f);
    glEnd();
```

Result is:

[image: result]

However, it is not exactly underneath.

How to do it?

Comment: So why do you expect this code to result in another output than the one you got? If you draw this on paper, you will see that the output is exactly what it should be.

Comment: I recommend learning OpenGL 3.3 or later instead of the old OpenGL. learnopengl.com is a great resource for it.

Comment: Since the x-coordinates of the two quads do not match, it's not wonder that they aren't exactly underneath each other.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the problem, you should first think in terms of position and dimension of your shapes:

```
/* It seems that your windows lies on [-1,1][-1,1] square. */
/* dimension of squares: {width, height} 
   here rectangle since width is equal to height 
   The two rectangles have the same dimension.
   */       
float dim[2] = {0.25f, 0.25f};

/* position of the rectangle centers, here you can see that the first is above
   this array must be read like {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}}
*/
float pos[2][2] = {{0.0f, 0.4f},{0.0f, -0.4f}};


glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    glVertex2f(pos[0][0] - dim[0], pos[0][1] - dim[1]);
    glVertex2f(pos[0][0] + dim[0], pos[0][1] - dim[1]);
    glVertex2f(pos[0][0] + dim[0], pos[0][1] + dim[1]);
    glVertex2f(pos[0][0] - dim[0], pos[0][1] + dim[1]);

    glColor3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    glVertex2f(pos[1][0] - dim[0], pos[1][1] - dim[1]);
    glVertex2f(pos[1][0] + dim[0], pos[1][1] - dim[1]);
    glVertex2f(pos[1][0] + dim[0], pos[1][1] + dim[1]);
    glVertex2f(pos[1][0] - dim[0], pos[1][1] + dim[1]);        
glEnd();
```